# Least-squares solution to almost-linear equations with a few cross-terms

Tags: least-squares, pseudoinverse

I have an intermediate number of equations N (say, 15) that I'd like to solve in a least-squares manner for M unknowns (M

To clarify, I have a set up with unknowns $x_i$like:
$y_1 = a_1 x_1 + b_1 x_3$
$y_2 = a_2 x_2 + b_2 x_3$
and so on.

A small percentage of the equations are of the format
$y_9 = a_9 x_9 + b_9 x_5 + c_9 x_1 x_2$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this solution. We seem to be in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. Consider the complete polynomial through order 2:
$$
 z(x,y) = \underbrace{a_{00}}_{0} + 
\underbrace{a_{10} x + a_{01} y}_{\text{order }1} + 
\underbrace{a_{20} x^{2} + a_{11} xy + a_{02} y^{2}}_{\text{order }2}
$$
Is the cross term $xy$ what you are after?

There are $m$ measurements $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k}, z_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}.$

The linear system is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} a &= z \\
\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
  1 & x_{1} & y_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & x_{1}y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} \\
  1 & x_{2} & y_{2} & x_{2}^{2} & x_{2}y_{2} & y_{2}^{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots &  \vdots &  \vdots &  \vdots \\
  1 & x_{m} & y_{m} & x_{m}^{2} & x_{m}y_{m} & y_{m}^{2} \\
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  a_{00}\\ a_{10} \\ a_{01} \\ a_{20} \\ a_{11} \\ a_{02}
\end{array} \right]
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  z_{1} \\ z_{2} \\ \vdots \\ z_{m}
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
Typically, you will have full column rank, and the unique least squares solution will be
$$
 a_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{+} b = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \, \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} b
$$